# How to implement C3 chart zoom functionality on a button click

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am new to C3 chart. I found the zoom functionality in the documentation for [C3](http://c3js.org/samples/interaction_zoom.html) . It will work for the mouse wheel scroll. But what I want is to implement the zoomin and zoomout in two seperate buttons. Can anyone direct me to the right track.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here below is an example of zoom in/out managed with buttons.
However unlike mouse wheel you have to decide which starting point to use.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 350, 150, 100, 400, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 100, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 350, 150, 100, 400, 350, 220, 250, 300, 270, 140, 150, 90, 150, 50, 120, 70, 40]
        ]
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        rescale: true,
        onzoom: function (domain) { 
         console.log("zoom", domain);
        }
    }
});

var zoom = 1;
var zoom_factor = 1.1;
var min = 0;
var max = chart.data()[0].values.length;

$("#zoom-in").click(function() {
 if (zoom<5) zoom *= zoom_factor;
  console.log("zoom-in", min, max, zoom);
 chart.zoom([min, max/zoom]);
});

$("#zoom-out").click(function() {
 if (zoom>1) zoom /= zoom_factor;
  console.log("zoom-out", min, max, zoom);
 chart.zoom([min, max/zoom]);
});

$("#zoom-reset").click(function() {
 zoom = 1;
  console.log("zoom-reset", min, max, zoom);
 chart.zoom([min, max/zoom]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>

<button id="zoom-in">zoom-in</button>
<button id="zoom-out">zoom-out</button>
<button id="zoom-reset">zoom-reset</button>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @beaver. But un unfortunately my chart is not zooming when I click on the zoom in button. There is no error. Manually when I scroll the mouse it is working. Any idea why?

Comment: Your code is working fine. But when I implement in my code it is not working. What I found was in your code when I trigger the chart.zoom() in console I am getting chart.zoom();
(2) [-0.53, -0.53] But when I do it in mine I am getting a date value..(2) [Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), Thu Jan 01 1970 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)]. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: please share your code. Otherwise it's impossible to check your implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a a solution to this that works in conjonction with mouse whell and preserves current scroll position.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['sample', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 350, 150, 100, 400, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 100, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250, 150, 200, 170, 240, 350, 150, 100, 400, 350, 220, 250, 300, 270, 140, 150, 90, 150, 50, 120, 70, 40]
        ]
    },
    zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        rescale: true,
        onzoom: function (domain) { 
         console.log("zoom", domain);
        }
    }
});

var zoom_factor = 3;
var min = 0;
var max = chart.data()[0].values.length;

$("#zoom-in").click(function() {
 const zoom = chart.zoom();
 const newZoom = [zoom[0] + zoom_factor , zoom[1] - zoom_factor];
 if (newZoom[1] - newZoom[0] > 0) chart.zoom(newZoom);
});

$("#zoom-out").click(function() {
 const zoom = chart.zoom();
    // Bound zoom to min and max
 chart.zoom([Math.max(zoom[0] - zoom_factor, min), Math.min(zoom[1] + zoom_factor , max)]);
});

$("#zoom-reset").click(function() {
  console.log("zoom-reset", min, max);
 chart.zoom([min, max]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.13/c3.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.7.13/c3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<button id="zoom-in">zoom-in</button>
<button id="zoom-out">zoom-out</button>
<button id="zoom-reset">zoom-reset</button>
<div id="chart"></div>
```